# How read a pchar using ReadProcessMemory

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm using the `ReadProcessMemory` function to read the content of an external running app, I have a memory address which points to a PChar(UNICODE). I'm wondering which is the proper way to get that value back to a string variable?

Now i'm using this code, but is not working

```
var
c : char;

repeat
  if not ReadProcessMemory(ph, Address, @c, sizeof(c), BytesRead) then
    raise exception.create(syserrormessage(getlasterror));
  result:=result+c;
  Address:=pointer(integer(address)+sizeof(c));
until (c=#0#0) or (BytesRead<>sizeof(c));
```

This error is raised

> Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was
>   completed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading past the string: you are not reading bytes but chars, so compare the null terminator with a char, that is:

```
until (c=#0) or (BytesRead<>sizeof(c));
```

`#0` is already 2 bytes,`#0#0` is 4 bytes (it cannot be equal to *any* Char).

When you read past the string and *"into an area of the process that is inaccessible"* (as per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) an error is returned.